# Free Nodejs hosts that don't need git to deploy

Tags: node.js, git, github, deployment, hosts

I mean that it doesn't need git to init or deploy. It's purely standalone with its own CLI or something like it and it's free.

It seems `nodejitsu` is gone or something and `convox` wasn't sure what they were doing.

Oh, and this is for small apps with no large scalability in mind.

Any good ones out there? Thanks.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: ok, i guess if there's any way to use heroku without git at all that would be nice too.

Comment: use http://glitch.com it has an ide with hosting

Comment: use heroku.com . This website provides free hosting for Node.js. But it provides feature of deploying via Dropbox, Heroku CLI and Git. You can choose Dropbox or Heroku CLI option for deploying your files.

Answer (score 0):

You will not get a good free server to deploy your apps. But you can get close to free. Some VPS providers can give you several months of their servers for free if you register with coupon links (e.g. see coupon links for [Digital Ocean](https://m.do.co/c/64b6b577b3de) and [Vultr](http://www.vultr.com/?ref=7107329)) but it will not be as convenient as Heroku or nodejitsu. With a VPS you will have to manage your own system, but it will fit your need for: "purely standalone with its own CLI or something like it and it's free" at least for few months and then you'll have to pay something like $2.50 per month which is almost as good as free, especially considering that you can host hundreds of small websites on a single VPS.